# Error adding Starship command line in Windows PowerShell profile

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line, scoop-installer

I added scoop, then Starship just as the Starship official [website](https://starship.rs/guide/#%F0%9F%9A%80-installation) says using the command `scoop install starship`. Then I added the line copied from the Starship website to the PowerShell profile:

```
Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)
```

But it throws this error to the PowerShell window:
`Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.`

This is the only line in my PowerShell `$Profile`.

But where is the problem, can you please figure out? The error is in the image below:

[image]

Comment: What is *starship*? You're referencing the official website. Why don't you provide it? The official help for [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1) shows that the command should be a string enclosed in quotes or double quotes. Why are you using parenthesis? If `starship` is an external executable shouldn't `Invoke-Command` be the better option for this purpose?

Comment: Yes. After adding "" quotation, it seems to work. Thank you so much for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple solution**

```
Invoke-Expression (& 'C:\Users\psayeed1990\scoop\apps\starship\current\starship.exe' init powershell --print-full-init | Out-String)
```

Change the link of your starship.exe as you need.

For further read, **This is how I solved this...**

*Creating the file with notepad didn't work for me*

First, if your PowerShell **$profile** doesn't exist, create a profile with this command in command line (creating the file with Notepad doesn't work).

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE)) {

  New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force

}
```

Second, if you command **notepad $profile**, you can see, edit and save the file. Copy this code from [official Starship site](https://starship.rs/) and paste it in the end of the $profile file `Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)`.

Third, if it doesn't work, you may want to install vcredist2019. **scoop install vcredist2019** didn't work for me. So, I downloaded from the [official site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Fourth, installing the vcredist2019 didn't solve it too. As @Olaf pointed out in the comment, you need **quotation mark** instead of parentheses, `Invoke-Expression "&starship init powershell"`.

I don't think quotation is the way to write. If you restart your PowerShell and it doesn't work yet, you may still see a error or a line giving you the command with exact path to the Starship executable.

Fifth, replace the above code `Invoke-Expression "&starship init powershell"` in the ***$profile*** with that line.

```
Invoke-Expression (& 'C:\Users\psayeed1990\scoop\apps\starship\current\starship.exe' init powershell --print-full-init | Out-String)
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Glad you got it working, will delete my now redundant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the execution of PowerShell scripts first.
To do so, run the following command as Administrator:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: That is only necessary if PowerShell scripts needs to be executed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Expression (& 'C:\Program Files\starship\bin\starship.exe' init powershell)`

in your $PROFILE after installing starship with `winget install starship`.

Answer (score 0):

`Add-Content -Path $PROFILE -Value 'Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)'`

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`