# The string is missing the terminator: '. - every time PowerShell is opened

Tags: powershell

Recieve this message every time PowerShell is opened

```
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I went to install starship prompt, added `Invoke-Expression (&starship init powershell)` to my powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 via notepad $PROFILE and get this error every time I open PowerShell (starship not running)

Have tried commenting out and deleting the line then saving the powershell profile, same error.

Any ideas where this could be coming from please? Thanks.

Comment: [Similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69065915/9898643)

Comment: Thanks, yes that is similar and I did check that thread before posting this but unfortunately I think this issue is nothing to do with starship.